# onDataChange in addListenerForSingleValueEvent fired twice

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In firebase the `onDataChange` is called twice everytime the code inside the if condition is executed.
 Here is my code.

```
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
         if(snapshot.child("visité").getValue().toString().equals(visité.getText().toString())
             && snapshot.child("date").getValue().toString().equals(date.getText().toString())
             && snapshot.child("zone").getValue().toString().equals(zone.getText().toString())
             && snapshot.child("etat").getValue().toString().equals("Créé")){
                 mDB.child(visiteur).child(snapshot.getKey()).removeValue();
                 loadData();
         } else {
             Toast.makeText(context,getString(R.string.suppr_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     }
}
```

After reading similar questions i think it's caused by the loop inside onDataChange. How do i get the loop out of onDataChange ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onDataChange` is called every time the data is changed(added, deleted, updated, moved ...), you are using `removeValue()` so it will call the method that's why it's called twice.

Comment: Is there any way i can get it no get called only once ?

Comment: using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` will call the `onDataChange` once

Comment: the addDataChange is already inside the addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Comment: is there an other event listener

Comment: The addDataChange wasn't triggered twice i just misplaced the else. Thank you for your help @Oussama